# HTTP request on 3G doesn't work

Tags: ios, http, 3g

I try to send HTTP request from my Iphone to local server that run on my local network (behind a router).
I forwarded the port on my router as follow:[image]

HTTP request is :

```
 NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://213.57.x.x:8080/OurDogsServerV2/DoggizzMain"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setAllowsCellularAccess:YES];
```

Over Wifi everything is working fine but I want to test 3G network (for end user).
I set a break point on doPost at my server (Apachi) so I don't think its time interval problem because I don't even get to my BP.

(I disabled my firewall).

I tried to change the url to `http://213.57.x.x:8080/localhost:8080/OurDogsServerV2/` and some other combinations.

Can somebody suggest what else can I try?

Comment: you are able to browse to http://213.57.x.x:8080/ with safari over 3g?

Comment: Manuel van Rijn :I can access my Apachi page only when I turn on Wifi but not with 3G, I think its because I still remain in local network when I turn the Wifi.Tnx.

Comment: I thought so two. A quick tip, you might want to take a look at https://ngrok.com/. You can do something like ngrok 8080 which will create a public url, tunneling traffic to your machine's port 8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was totally my fault. In the options of my router I did disable the ***WAN Blocking*** but I didn't notice the apply button in the bottom (I think I assumed that apply button for port forwarding will include that option).